# delete a folder in java

Tags: java

The folder I need to delete is one that is created from my program. The directory is not the same on every pc so the folder code I am using is

```
userprofile+"\\Downloads\\Software_Tokens"
```

There will be files in, so I guess i need to recursively delete it. I looked at some samples for that here but it never accepts my path. The path works fine in the code as an environmental variable, because i added code for it

`static String userprofile = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");`

so can someone just show me the code with my path plugged please?

Comment: Consider using File.separator instead of "\\" or "/" characters

Comment: What is the value of the `userprofile` variable? Can you try to print out `userprofile+"\\Downloads\\Software_Tokens"` and see if it results into a valid path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use apache library ! You can do it recursively.

```
  String directory = userprofile + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + "Software_Tokens";
  if (!directory.exists()) {
      System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
      System.exit(0);
  } else {
      try {
          delete(directory);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(0);
      }
  }
  System.out.println("Done");
  }
  public static void delete(File file)
   throws IOException {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
          //directory is empty, then delete it
          if (file.list().length == 0) {
              file.delete();
              System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
          } else {
              //list all the directory contents
              String files[] = file.list();
              for (String temp: files) {
                  //construct the file structure
                  File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);

                  //recursive delete
                  delete(fileDelete);
              }
              //check the directory again, if empty then delete it
              if (file.list().length == 0) {
                  file.delete();
                  System.out.println("Directory is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
              }
          }
      } else {
          //if file, then delete it
          file.delete();
          System.out.println("File is deleted : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
```

Comment: @GETah Yep..I realized that mistake and i edited the answer.Thanks Anyway.

Comment: I feel like using the overly tested API is definitely a better choice than your solution that may hide other bugs than the one already spotted ;-)

Comment: that worked! I tried the apache method below but FileUtils gives an error and I am sure I need to do something to add the apachi api

Answer (score 1):

If your directory is not empty, you may use the [Apache Commons IO API](http://commons.apache.org/io/)'s method [deleteDirectory(File file)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29) :

```
String toDelete = userprofile + File.separator + "Downloads" + 
        File.separator + "Software_Tokens";
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(toDelete));
```

Be careful with the `/` or `\` that are system dependent and use `File.separator` instead.